# How to publish Drive App for Shared Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-drive-shared-drive

I have published a drive app that works fine for my drive. But it does not show up when i am in Shared Drive. Do I have to republish or re-install the app Or 
my System Admin will install that app and that will reflect in everyone's account. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I Found it myself after few hours of R&D. If you want to enable your Drive Installable App to be appear in Shared Drive then check the checkbox titled as Shared Drive Support and click save